# Postgres full-text search - how to split numbers and words if written wihtout a space between them

Tags: postgresql, full-text-search

So, in our corpus we've got quite a few amounts with units. But unfortunately they are sometimes written as 10ml and sometimes as 10 ml, for example. This is both in the corpus and in user queries.

So I want `select to_tsvector('10ml')` to give me `'10':1 'ml':2`.

Is there any way to configure postgres FTS to split the number and unit out into separate lexemes? I know it is possible using a custom function to process the documents/queries but would be nicer to change the text search config. It looks like it should be possible considering it has a separate numword call for parsing.

Comment: You would have to write your own parser in C for this to work. A workaround could be a [synonym dictionary](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/textsearch-dictionaries.html#TEXTSEARCH-SYNONYM-DICTIONARY) that replaces 10ml with 10, but that dictionary would have to contain a line for each possible amount.

Comment: You don't want to use custom functions?

Comment: "considering it has a separate numword call for parsing"  That makes it easy to exclude those types of words altogether, or apply different stemming rules to them, but doesn't facilitate much else.  If you were going to write new C code to do something useful with the numword category, it would probably be easier to put that C code into a parser, to avoid generating that category in the first place and generate two separate tokens instead.